# tkagg and python3.3.2 in different directory

Tags: matplotlib, backend, python-3.3

I have installed installed python to

```
/opt/python3.3/
```

in Ubuntu 13.04

I installed successfully the matplotlib (it works in ipython3 notebook in inline mode) but without any backend for GUI Style output.

I had problems finding any backend which is compatible with python3.3.
My problem is when I build matplotlib from source:

```
python3 setup.py build
```

with the ubuntu python3 version it finds all dependencies for `TkAgg` and shows that in the output!
I installed also `tk-dev` and other related packages in ubuntu

But when I try to use my python3.3  like

```
/opt/python3.3/bin/python3 setup.py build
```

it does not find any dependencies at all????
Why is this? I did not want to install another python into the system `/usr/local/...`
I wanted a clean install folder of python with all necessary packages I need
But I cant install matplotlib.

Comment: It does not find the dependencies in it's search path.  You need to either tell it to look in `/usr/local` or install all of the dependencies in `/opt`

Comment: also, `easy_install` is being replaced by `pip`